# How do i copy an item in an list into a list in another activity?

Tags: java, android

Been trying to add a favorites system to this notes app where I can tap and hold an item in the list view to add it to another activity with a list view. Here is the activity with the first list.

Items are added via the MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savebutton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText editTextHeading = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
                EditText editTextContent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contentfield);
                String heading = editTextHeading.getText().toString().trim();
                String content = editTextContent.getText().toString().trim();
                if (!heading.isEmpty()) {
                    if(!content.isEmpty()) {
                        try {
                            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput(heading + ".txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //heading will be the filename
                            fileOutputStream.write(content.getBytes());
                            fileOutputStream.close();
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }else {
                        editTextContent.setError("Content can't be empty!");
                    }
                }else{
                    editTextHeading.setError("Heading can't be empty!");
                }
                editTextContent.setText("");
                editTextHeading.setText("");
            }
        });

        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_gotosaved);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, saved.class));
            }
        });

        Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_faves);
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, favorites.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Items added will be viewed here

```
public class saved extends MainActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.notes.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_saved);
        File files = getFilesDir();
        String[] array = files.list();
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        for (String filename : array) {
            filename = filename.replace(".txt", "");
            System.out.println(filename);
            adapter.add(filename);
        }
        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_saved);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String item = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Note.class);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, item);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                String item = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

And tapping and holding an item from there should "favorite" it and copy it to this new activity with another listview

```
public class favorites extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorites);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_favorites);

    }

}
```

How should I approach this?

Comment: I see you're sending an intent with the data you need in the other activity already, so why not get the items you've been putting by using getIntent() in the other activity and get from it the data you've put ?, pardon me if I didn't understand your request correctly :thinking:

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#getIntent()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your implementation of creating an individual .txt file in the default directory for each note, this is how you could implement:

```
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            String item = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Boolean isItemFavorite = item.contains("_favorite");
            if (!isItemFavorite){
                File itemFile = new File(item + ".txt");
                File favoriteItemFile = new File(item + "_favorite.txt");
                itemFile.renameTo(favoriteItemFile);
            }
        }
    });
```

Then in your "favorites" activity you could access all of your note .txt file the same as you do in your "saved" activity - just filtering out any items that don't contain "_favorite" in your "String[] array = files.list();"

Also, some tips: follow naming convention with your activities. "saved" should at least start with an uppercase letter and really should be named something like "SavedNotesListActivity". Also, you should use a room database to keep track of your notes. You should have a favorites table in your room database to keep track of all of your favorites.

Comment: That does seem like the answer I'm looking for, but it is giving me an error saying that its missing a return statement? do i just shove in a return true; in there?

Comment: Yes, just return true;